# change file permission using java?

Tags: android, file-permissions

I need to change file permission using  java .i used runtime.exec() to run shell commands but i am not able to change permission of  this particular file /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor .

Comment: Without rooted device, and using runtime.exec() you can't.

Answer (score 0):

you must be root for that to work